# Custom entityID in SAML configuration FoxIDs

Tags: openid, saml, foxids

I am configuring SAML 2.0 as 'Up-parties' in [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) [single identity provider](https://www.itfoxtec.com).
Documentation is clear and there are lots of custom settings, but I need to change default (autogenerated) **entityID**.
That property I have share in *EntityDescriptor* section in METADATA I am uploading on my identity provider.

Comment: please provide more details. Please check SAML specs. You are uploading a SP Metadata to your IDP? You need to change your SP settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting a [SAML 2.0 IdP as up-party](https://www.foxids.com/docs/up-party-saml-2.0) in FoxIDs. You can configure / change the autogenerated `EntityID` by clicking `Show advanced settings` and adding the wanted `EntityID` value in the `Optional custom SP issuer` field.

Answer (score 0):

As I found 'Optional custom SP issuer' field is changing *entityID*.
I think it can help me.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: The field is still called "Optional custom SP issuer". The ID is default auto generated.